# Selecting top 75% tuples in extended relational algebra

Tags: relational-algebra

I'm currently trying to "List the names of the top 75% of employees in terms of total revenues of orders processed.".

I've made a table with the revenue and their names and sorted it by revenue. How would I select an amount of tuples? I could COUNT how many there are, but it's not like I could use that result directly to filter out an amount of tuples.

How would I do something like this in extended relational algebra?

Comment: Please give a reference for this algebra;

Comment: I'm not sure you can in relational algebra and I'm not quite good enough to answer you in the extended one.